# How to add string value in confirm function of JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have JavaScript function in my asp button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCommission" runat="server" Text="Deposit Commission" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to deposit commission into points?')) return false;" OnClick="btnCommission_Click" />
```

but I want to value `<%= (commission_total)%>` in my confirm function like this :

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to deposit' + <%= (commission_total)%> + 'commission into points?')) return false;"
```

but it doesn't allow me to add this value saying "this is not scriptlet". But I want to confirm how much they are going to deposit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grab the value the user entered from wherever they entered it using JavaScript. Let's say the user's entering the value into some textbox that looks like this: `<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="myAmount" />`. We could then grab the value like this: `document.querySelector('input[id$="myAmount"]').value`. So, you could use this as follows:

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to deposit' + document.querySelector('input[id$="myAmount"]').value + 'commission into points?')) return false;"
```

This is one of the possible solutions. Because the `OnClientClick` event happens before postback, you'll have to do this in JavaScript. If you don't want to do this in JavaScript, you'll have to let postback happen and handle open a popup to confirm the amount. If you want to do it this way, you might look into using the [Ajax Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or something similar to open a window after the user clicks the button.

I hope that helps.

### Update

You could use a hidden field and update the hidden field with the value. Then you could grab that value from JavaScript and show it in the confirm dialog. Here's the markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showValue() {
            var val = document.querySelector('#<%= test1.ClientID %>').value;
            return confirm('Is this correct? ' + val);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="test1" ></asp:HiddenField>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="tester" OnClientClick="showValue();" Text="Show" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected double test;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = 12.50;

            test1.Value = test.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you don't have to assign the value of the hidden field on page load. You can do it wherever makes the most sense for the site you're building.

Comment: Or, if you're using jQuery, the selector would be like this: `$('input[id$="myAmount"]').val()`.

Comment: but my commission_total is a variable and its value coming from server side

Comment: So, is the commission_total not displayed on the site before the user submits it?

Comment: it is displaying but for some reason when i add in confirm messgae its not working....

Comment: Well, one option is to grab the value from wherever it's displayed with JavaScript altering the selector provided above. Another option is to look into using something like the Ajax Toolkit's [Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx). That way everything would be in C#, but it might require additional postbacks.

Comment: when i check at runtime its displaying like <input type="submit" name="ctl00$Content$btnCommission" value="Deposit Commission" onclick="if (!confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to deposit&#39; + &lt;%= (commission_total)%> + &#39;commission into points?&#39;)) return false;" id="Content_btnCommission" />

Comment: and error is : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48384/discussion-between-user207888-and-jvdub)

Comment: Sorry, I can't join a chat right now. Can you post your ASP markup?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a solution using hidden fields. It seems to be one of the better options given the circumstances.

Comment: thanks, worked for me with some modification as it was always hitting server side if if i cancelled on confirm function:   so i added :  OnClientClick="if (showValue()== true) return true; else return false;"

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you could accept my answer, that'd be great!

Comment: sure i can but how to do that?